# Angular ChangeDetectorRef: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-changedetection

I am receiving the following error with ChangeDetectorRef. Not sure why its suddenly occurring, when other components utilize ChangeDetectorRef. Does anyone know how to solve? Its linking to a Kendo Grid selection.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

```
export class DocumentPropertyGridComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  public documentPropertyGridDataSelected: Array<DocumentPropertyGridData> = new Array<DocumentPropertyGridData>();

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { 
  }

  selectTest(e){
    this.documentPropertyGridDataSelected = e.selectedRows;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  Selected Count: {{documentPropertyGridDataSelected.length}}
<div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the `this` context (BTW, how is the function called?). Fixable by converting it to an arrow function

```
  selectTest = (e) => {
    this.documentPropertyGridDataSelected = e.selectedRows;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: Wow! I was passing a private function as a callback reference to a subscribe!
It seems JavaScript was immediately executing the function content instead of calling it later on after subscribe call is triggered.
Thank you so much!